# c# barrier and exception handeling

Tags: c#, exception, barrier

I have created simple c# example which uses barriers and I have thrown an exception inside one of functions and I'm getting unexpected result

```
phase 1 of DoWork1
phase 2 of DoWork2
phase 3 of DoWork3
Current phase 0
phase 2 of DoWork3
phase 2 of DoWork1
phase 3 of DoWork2
//so far everything is fine, lets throw an exception now

DoWork1 canceled
phase3 of DoWorn1

//end
```

now as You can see in Code I have thrown an exception in `DoWork1` method and I expected  that all 3 method will handle exception, but only first one does, second problem is that only first method prints "phase 3 bla bla" and I expected all 3 of them to print it to console. Could Someone explain me why does this happen

[Code](http://pastebin.com/YYbLBeEQ) is a bit long but most of it is just copy paste

Comment: Why do you expect an Exception in t1 to surface in t2 and t3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an exception thrown on one thread will not generally be available on any other threads. Exceptions travel up the call stack, and each thread has its own stack.

Second, the reason the other two methods never reach phase 3 is that when `DoWork1` throws the exception, it's because it tried to wait for the other participants in this barrier and failed. At that point, the barrier no longer believes that `DoWork1` is waiting for the other participants, so when the other two `SignalAndWait()`, they wait forever, because `DoWork1` never `SignalAndWait`s again.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has its own call stack. so only the thread in which you are throwing the exception the exception will be caught.